# SAS: Regressions of times around an event

Tags: events, sas, regression

I am reading myself into event studies and need to regress the pre-announcement day volatility (daily) on the announcement days t0 and t1

```
Return(t0,t+1) = Volatility(t-5 to t-1) + Controls.
```

thus, I tried to create a dummy which is 0 in t-5 until t-1 and 1 in t0 and t+1. Then I set return to . if dummy not equal 1 and volatility to . if dummy not equal 0. Then:

```
proc reg data=regdata;
    model return = volatility + control1 + control2; 
quit;
```

Obviously, dependent and independent variables' data is in different observations. The program has no valid observations.

```
Event_time  return  volatility
-5                     0.5
-4                     0.4
-3                     0.6
-2                     0.2
-1                     0.4 
 0            0.05
 1            0.06
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: short answer is to transform the data, putting the volatility value on the appropriate return record.  Give that a shot and if you get stuck, post that question.

Comment: That's what I did (I averaged the 5 days before and made one record each). You mention 'transform', what proc do you recommend?

Comment: Post what your current data looks like? You can use PROC TRANSPOSE to restructure your data.

Comment: The way you used your dummy variable `return` and `volatility` are perfectly separated: one of them is always missing, hence SAS complaining that there are no valid observations.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. They are separated. Is there a way to 'spread' the announcement day observation over the 5 days prior announcement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by doing a proc means by stock and re-merging the new day 0 and 1 mean value to the pre-announcement window.